# visualforce page for excel and pdf print

Tags: visualforce

I just created a visualforce page using excel layout (columns and rows) to print excel and pdf file. I am getting some styling problem. The sheet have 7 columns in total, I want to display two text block by side, text block A on column 1 and text block B on column 7 when previewing or exporting the file. Please let me know if there's other solutions that work better!

Right now i just discoverd two solutions:

(1) using ,  and colspan to display the block -> works well when export but two blocks are faraway when I preview the pdf/excel

```
    <div id="legal-invoice">
    <ul>
        <li>Date: </li>
        <li>Customer: </li>
        <li>Address: </li>
        <li>VAT Nr: </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>No. </li>
        <li> <br/> </li>
        <li> <br/> </li>
        <li>PO/ WO Date: </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(2) using ul, li -> looks nice on preview but the text blocks are above and below when export to excel.

```
<div class = "table" style="display: inline-block; justify-content: space-between;">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <div class = "left-table"> 
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">
                        <span>Date: </span>
                        <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>Customer: </span>
                        <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>Address: </span>
                        <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>VAT Nr: </span>
                        <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                </td>
                </div>
                <td colspan = "3"></td>
                <div class = "right-table">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span>No. </span>
                    <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <span>PO/ WO Date: </span>
                    <span>{!IF(field_c != null, field_c, 'N/A')}</span>
                </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.